# How to update role definition of a group in sharepoint 2010 programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a SharePoint group programmatically with read and contribute roles.
Now I am trying to update the roles of that group with other role definitions. Like full control etc. But I can't remove the existing roles from the SharePoint group.

Comment: What does "but i cant remove the existing roles from the sharepoint group" mean exactly? Error? What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code. You first need to determine the roledefinition (assuming you are using an existing one). After that add group to role, followed by adding role to web:

```
public enum RoleTypeEnum { fullcontrol, design, contribute, read };

 //declare roledefinition
 SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition;

 //switch to determine role
 switch (roleType)
 {
      case RoleTypeEnum.contribute:
          roleDefinition = spWeb.RoleDefinitions[Constants.SiteCollection.SecurityTypeNames.contribute];
          break;
      case RoleTypeEnum.design:
          roleDefinition = spWeb.RoleDefinitions[Constants.SiteCollection.SecurityTypeNames.design];
          break;
      case RoleTypeEnum.fullcontrol:
          roleDefinition = spWeb.RoleDefinitions[Constants.SiteCollection.SecurityTypeNames.fullcontrol];
          break;
      case RoleTypeEnum.read:
          roleDefinition = spWeb.RoleDefinitions[Constants.SiteCollection.SecurityTypeNames.read];
          break;
      default:
          return null;
}

//add group to role
SPGroup group = spWeb.SiteGroups[groupName];
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);

//add role to web
spWeb.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
spWeb.Update();
```

The constants I used in the switch are dutch but here they are:

```
            public static partial class SecurityTypeNames
        {
            public const string fullcontrol = "Volledig beheer";

            public const string design = "Ontwerpen";

            public const string contribute = "Bijdragen";

            public const string read = "Lezen";

        }
```